# Paging from Array and display ....?

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

```
   <?php 

    $B = array(
      0=>1,
      1=>2,
      2=>3,
      3=>4,
      4=>5,
      5=>6,
      6=>7,
      7=>8,
      8=>9,
      9=>10,
      10=>11
    );

    function pagination_from_array($arr, $show_per_page, $page=1){

        $start = $show_per_page * ($page-1);
        $end   = $show_per_page * $page;


         for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){
            echo ">>>".$arr[$i]."<br>";
         }
       if($end-1 < count($arr)) {
            echo '............';
        }

    }

    pagination_from_array($B , 6, $_GET['page']);
    /*
    //Dislay in html table
    //=> page1
        key | value
        0     1
        1     2
        2     3
        3     4
        4     5
        5     6

        ........

    //=> page 2
        key | value
        6     7
        7     8
        8     9
        9     10
        10    11
       total  1+2+3+..+11

    */

    ?>
```

Could anyone help me to implement this?

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here. What do you mean "implement this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem: `$i` is a negative number as  `$show_per_page * ($page-1);` equals -6
So when your referencing `$arr[$i]` it's not displaying anything because there is nothing at index -6, You could try something like the [abs()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php), Example:

```
 for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){
    echo ">>>".$arr[abs($i)]."<br>";
 }
```

UPDATE:

Well it's actually this: `$_GET['page']` that's causing the negative value for the index in your example.

UPDATE #2:

Well I went along and quickly created this, hope this gets you started:

```
// Page Count
$page_count = 100;

// Build the array
for($p = 1; $p <= $page_count; $p++) {
    $pages[] = $p;
}

// Print the array for testing
//echo print_r($pages, true)."\n";

function pagination_from_array($arr, $show_per_page, $page=1){
    $total_pages = count($arr);
    $paginate_total_pages = $total_pages / $show_per_page;

    $start = $show_per_page * ($page-1);
    $end   = $show_per_page * $page;

    //echo "Start: ".$start."\n";
    //echo "End: ".$end."\n";
    //echo "Total: ".$total_pages."\n";
    //echo "Pageinate: ".$paginate_total_pages."\n";
    //echo "Page: ".$page."\n";

    if(($paginate_total_pages) + 1 < $page) {
        return; // no pages to display
    }

    if($total_pages < $start) {
        return; // no pages to display
    }

    for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++){
        if(array_key_exists(abs($i),$arr)) {
            echo ">>>".$arr[abs($i)]."<br />\n";
        }        
    }

    if($end-1 < count($arr)) {
        echo "............<br />\n";
    }
}

$display_pages = 6;
$pages_to_display = (count($pages) / $display_pages) + 1;
echo "Pages to display: ".$pages_to_display."\n";

for($d = 1; $d <= $pages_to_display; $d++) {
    pagination_from_array($pages,$display_pages, $d);
    sleep(1);
}
```